# codeigniter image reader prob

Tags: codeigniter

Hi im making a image gallery in  useing the following tutorial at

http://superdit.com/2010/06/27/basic-image-gallery-with-codeigniter/

i keep getting this error

wrong parameter count for strstr()

google'd and tried this and found i needed to remove a third parameter.

I removed the third parameter from line38 $ext = strrev(strstr(strrev($file), ".", TRUE));

now all errors are gone but the image uploading will not work any ideas why this is now failing ?????

Thanks Alan

Answer (score 0):

hi I think that tutorial using PHP 5.3 so the strstr function has the third parameter